# Why do we prefer to use $i$ with generators in Lie Algebra

Tags: group-theory, conventions, lie-algebra, complex-numbers, unitarity

I am reading A. Zee. Group theory in a Nutshell for Physicists and for some reason, he prefers to write the generators with an $i$ near them

For example, a rotation can simply be described as:

$$e^{\theta \mathcal{J}}$$
where:

$$\mathcal{J}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

but instead, we define $J=-i\mathcal{J}$ and write rotations as $e^{i\theta J}$.

Also, the generator for a boost is:

$$iK =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
so a boost is $e^{i\varphi K}$.

Also, we approximate a unitary operator as:

$$U(\epsilon) \approx I - i\epsilon \hat{H} \implies U(t) = e^{i\hat{H}t}$$

even though the $i$ is arbitrary. So why is that?

Edit:

So for the Time Evolution Operator part, [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/321230/lie-algebra-conventions-hermitian-vs-anti-hermitian) answers it (which is related to Hermitian Operators), but why should this be the case for rotations and boost? Is it because of quantum mechanics again? Why should the generator of rotations be hermitian?

Comment: Because then the generator is hermitian, which e.g. is desirable in quantum mechanics.. [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/321230/lie-algebra-conventions-hermitian-vs-anti-hermitian) might be of interest.

Comment: I understand that for the unitary operator, but for the boost and rotation, why?

Comment: In quantum mechanics we 'implement' symmetries as unitary (or antiunitary) operators, cf. [Wigner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lie Algebra Conventions: Hermitian vs. anti-Hermitian](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/321230/)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero It answers only the time evolution operator part. But I don't understand why should this be the case for rotations and boosts.

Comment: @Habouz, in physics complex $i$ basically means phase of $90^{\circ}$. Also see here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/428223/

Comment: Mathematicians don't bother with the *i*, for simplicity. In classical mechanics, rotations don't need the *i*. Some groups use it, some don't. Understand both.